# Using requests in Python to process GET request

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I posted another question but made a bit of a mess of it in the comments section. Basically, I am trying to use the requests library in Python in order to accomplish what I normally would by using CURL in order to process a GET request to an API. From what I have learned from a very helpful person here, I can process the request, as well as the authorisation header by doing the following:

Original CURL Command that I would normally use:

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: exapi:111:58d351234e1a:LA2' 'http://api.example.com/v1.14/user?id=1234'
```

This is the Python code I am using for my script:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://api.example.com/v1.14/user?id=1234"
headers = {"Authorization": "exapi:111:58d351234e1a:LA2"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print response.json
```

However, when I run my code, I receive `bound method response.json of <response [200]>` instead of data that I was expecting from the *GET*. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here? I am guessing that I am doing something wrong with my header but I am not sure.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your header. `response.json` is a method, you have to call it like so: `response.json()`.

Comment: Ah right...that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @juanpa.arrivilaga has already mentioned and as the `print`ed message clearly says, you need to call the bound `json` method. The source of confusion is likely from `content`, which is an attribute.

```
response.json()  # method
response.content # attribute
```

Comment: if you do that, you can get rid of `import json` as well

Answer (score -1):

How about using json module explicitly:

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
print data
```

Comment: Why not just use the method?

Comment: not to mix `.text` with `.json()` method as author did.